# Can't dynamically add anchor tag after enclosing div inside a div with data-role="page"

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want to dynamically add anchor tag to the `div="myDiv"`.
It works fairly as long as I didn't enclose it inside another dive with `data-role="page"`.
I want to enclose it in a page so that it can be called as page on a button link.What could be the problem.
Below is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script> -->
        <style>
            figure{
                float:left
            }
            figcaption{
                font-size: small;
            }
            img {
                float:left; 
            }
            a {
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:hover {
                color:black; 
                text-decoration:none; 
                cursor:pointer;  
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">   //remove this and it will start working.
            <div data-role="div" id="myDiv" ></div>
            <div data-role="popup" id="popupMap1" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function play(id){
                document.getElementById("popupMap1").innerHTML="<a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-theme='a' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'>Close</a><iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+id+"' width='480' height='320' seamless='' id='plyerIframe1'></iframe>";                    
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?time=today&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=15&format=5">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var title=new Array();
        var thumbnailUrl=new Array();
        var playerUrl=new Array();
        var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        var duration=new Array();
        var views=new Array();
        var idi=new Array();

        function showMyVideos2(data) {
            var feed = data.feed;
            var entries = feed.entry || [];
            var html = ['<ul class="videos">'];

            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = entries[i];
                title[i] = entry.title.$t.substr(0,20);
                thumbnailUrl[i] = entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
                playerUrl[i] = entry.media$group.media$content[0].url;
                duration[i]= entry.media$group.media$content[0].duration;
                views[i]= entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
                var aTag = document.createElement('a');
                aTag.setAttribute('href','#popupMap1');
                aTag.setAttribute('data-rel','popup');
                aTag.setAttribute('data-position-to','window');
                aTag.setAttribute('data-theme','b');
                aTag.setAttribute('data-inline','true');

                //idi[i]=playerUrl[i].substring(25,36);
                idi[i]=entry.media$group.yt$videoid.$t;

                aTag.innerHTML ="<figure  onclick='play(idi["+i+"])'><figcaption>"+title[i]+"...</figcaption><img src="+thumbnailUrl[i]+"  width='200px' height='150px' ><footer>Duration: "+duration[i]+" seconds<br><span>Total Views: "+views[i]+"</span></footer></figure>" ;
                mydiv.appendChild(aTag);    
            }                   
        }       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXRMZ/19/) with the solution for your problem.

### Explanation:

When you use the `data-role="page"` div, you're engaging jQuery-Mobile framework, which will perform some operations on the DOM, re-arranging some elements. I won't go any deeper into this as I'm really not sure what exactly goes on behind the scenes, but what seemed to be happening was that jQuery-Mobile had not yet finished rendering the page at the time the youtube script was trying to call `showMyVideos2`.

So I removed the `<script>` tag where you included that script, and instead added the following javascript code:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {
    $.getScript("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?time=today&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=15&format=5");
});
```

Two things you should know about this:

1. I've put this code in a callback for the [pageshow](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) event, to ensure that jQuery-Mobile has finished all the work it needs to do on the page before you start any DOM manipulation. Other jQuery-Mobile events such as `pagechange` and `pagecreate` would also have worked.
2. I loaded the youtube script using jQuery's [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method, which allows you to dynamically retrieve an external script and execute it. It is actually just a shorthand notation for the following case of the $.ajax() method:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?time=today&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=15&format=5",
     dataType: "script"
   });
   ```

Comment: I am using a footer with a button with a link to another similar page.But even after adding data-transition="slide"  sliding effect isn't coming as shown on jquerymobile website.what could be the problem?

<div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
   <a href="xyz.html" rel="external" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-transition="slideup">Home</a>
</div>

Comment: You should probably write up a separate question for that issue. I'm not really familiar with page transition animations, and its not likely that others will notice your comment :P